# In class composition make possible for contained class to access container class variables

Tags: c++

First consider the class declaration:

```
class Container
{
public:
    Container();
    void funcMember();
private:
    int dataMember;
};

class Contained
{
public:
    Contained();
    int contmember();
private:
    int somedata;
};
```

Now the idea is that the `Contained` class is made for being declared inside the `Container` class so it can be declared more than once and be created and deleted whenever you want, in this case from `funcMember()` in the `Container` class.

My question: Is there a way to make that every instance of `Contained` inside `Container` could access `dataMember` inside whatever `Container` instance?

Note: several `Contained` objects could hold different values in the `somedata` variable.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. There's `friend` if you meant accessing private members.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `friend` keyword? Also, it doesn't seem like `Container` uses `Contained` anywhere here.

Comment: Or make all the shared data members in its own class and pass it around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `friend` and a nested class to do so:

**`Container.h`**:

```
class Container
{
    class Contained; // <<< Forward declare
    friend class Contained; // <<< Allow access from Contained
    class Contained
    {
    public:
        Contained(Container& cont_) : cont(cont_) {}
        int contmember();
    private:
         int somedata;
         Container& cont;
    };
public:
    Container();
    void funcMember();
private:
    int dataMember;
};
```

In another TU provide the implementation seeing the fully declared `Container` class:

**`Container.cpp`**

```
#include "Container.h"

int Container::Contained::contmember() {
    return cont.dataMember + somedata;
}
```

Comment: wow, that is like what I have been looking for, but after this declaration how should I define 'contmember' so that:{somedata+=dataMember; cout<<somedata;} for example

Comment: @JuanMolina You need to pass a reference or pointer to `Container`  to `Contained` in such case. You cannot directly dereference having only a forward declaration at hand.

Comment: is `Contained(this);` a right way to create a new object in order to work?

Comment: In case of taking references it should be `Contained(*this);`. But generally, yes.